# Use a FOR loop within an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, loops, for-loop

So, what i'm trying to do is to send an AJAX request, but as you can see i have many fields in my form, and i use an array to make validations, i would like to use the same array, to pass the values to be sent via AJAX:

I never used the for loop in JS, but seems familiar anyway.

The way the loop is made, obviously wont work:

```
for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
        var required[i] = $('#'+required[i]).attr('value');
```

This will create the variables i want, how to use them?

HOPEFULLY, you guys can help me!!! Thank you very much!

```
required = ['nome','sobrenome','endereco','codigopostal','localidade','telemovel','email','codigopostal2','localidade2','endereco2','nif','entidade','codigopostal3','localidade3','endereco3','nserie','modelo'];              


function ajaxrequest() {
    for (i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
        var required[i] = $('#' + required[i]).attr('value');
        var dataString = 'nome=' + required[0] + '&sobrenome=' + required[1];
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxload/como.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $(".agendarleft").html("SUCESS");
        }
    });
```

Comment: how can i make a "for" loop, using an array?

Comment: Yeah it's not very clear. To have a stab at deciphering this; are you wondering how to get the values you're putting in your `required` array to be passed as key/value pairs in your POST request the way they would be if you'd submitted a form?

Comment: @Souza you've already made a for loop, as far as I can tell it should loop over every value in `required` and get values from fields with those IDs. You're not making yourself very well understood.

Comment: @Thor84no check out the var dataString, you think the output will be correct?

Comment: @Souza I don't know what you'd expect, so I can't tell you. Also I haven't got anywhere to execute this code right now, but I'd say you're not doing what you intend. It *looks* like you intend `dataString` to contain 'nome=<user-input>&sobrenome=<user-input>', but for that you should put it *after* the `for` loop, not inside. You should also define the array of values outside of the `for` loop and fill it inside it. Oh, and I'd store the values in a different array to the one you have the IDs in rather than overwrite it.

Comment: be careful with declaring variables inside of loops. Depending on the language, your variable will only be avaiable inside of the loop. I believe its fine with javascript but not a great habit to get into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To help ensure that the appropriate element IDs and values are passed, loop through the various elements and add the data to an object first.

**jQuery:**

```
required = ['nome', 'sobrenome', 'endereco', 'codigopostal', 'localidade', 'telemovel', 'email', 'codigopostal2', 'localidade2', 'endereco2', 'nif', 'entidade', 'codigopostal3', 'localidade3', 'endereco3', 'nserie', 'modelo'];

function ajaxrequest() {
    var params = {}; // initialize object

    //loop through input array
    for (var i=0; i < required.length; i++) {             
        // set the key/property (input element) for your object
        var ele = required[i]; 
        // add the property to the object and set the value
        params[ele] = $('#' + ele).val(); 
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxload/como.php",
        data: params,
        success: function() {
            $(".agendarleft").html("SUCESS");
        }
    });
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kPR69/

Comment: Changed this line : `params[i] = ele + '=' + $('#' + ele).attr('value');`  Anything else is perfect!!!! You're the man, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What would be much cleaner would be to put a class on each of the fields you wish to save and use this to iterate through them. Then you wouldn't need to specify the input names either and you could send a json object directly to the Service;

```
var obj = {};

$('.save').each(function () {

       var key = $(this).attr('id');
       var val = $(this).val();

       if (typeof (val) == "undefined")
           val = "''"

       obj[key] = val;
}
```

Then send obj as the data property of your AJAX call....

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code. 'required' is being overwritten and is also being re-declared inside of the loop.

I would suggest using pre-written library, a few I included below.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#validation

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Otherwise the follow would get you close. You  may need to covert the array into a string.

```
var required = ['nome','sobrenome'];              

function ajaxrequest() {
  var values;
  for (i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
    var values[i] = $('#' + required[i]).attr('value');
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxload/como.php",
    data: values,
    success: function() {
        $(".agendarleft").html("SUCESS");
    }
});
```

}