# How to scrape all values of AJAX search table with PYTHON?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the [CPU Specs Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/) at TechPowerUp.

I have found the table updates using AJAX and created the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import string

cpus = []

base = 'https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/?ajaxsrch='

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

letters.extend(range(0, 10))

for i in letters:
    URL = base + str(i)

    page = requests.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    with open('cpu2.csv', mode='a') as cpu_csv:
        headers = ['name', 'family', 'socket', 'release']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(cpu_csv, fieldnames=headers, lineterminator='\n')

        for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')

            if tds[0].text.strip() not in cpus:

                writer.writerow({'name': tds[0].text.strip(), 'family': tds[1].text.strip(), 'socket': tds[4].text.strip(), 'release': tds[8].text.strip()})

                cpus.append(tds[0].text.strip())

            else:
                print("duplicate")
```

This code works in the fact it loops through A-Z then 0-9 and populates a csv file ignoring duplicates however I'm getting a logical error where I am only scraping ~600 results where there are over 2000 entries.

I believe this may be due to a limit on the returned items for each AJAX Search request so not all entries are discovered, is there a different approach to fetch all results?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates then it should be only 606 records.Else you will get around 1800 records.

Comment: @KunduK 1740 to be accurate !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη : Yes I am getting 1739 records.

Comment: the difference number is the columns raw :)

Comment: If you look at the website link and go to the manufacter filter option it would indicate there are 2210 unique entries this is what's throwing me off.

Comment: Oh okay, i figured it out. `Time` restriction dude. well to solve that in order to get the full output. you need to `import datetime` and pass `unixtimestamp` to `_` parameter within the call !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη That sounds like exactly what's needed. Can you update your code answer to explain?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the table data using `pandas`.Get the data in `DataFrame` and import into csv.

**Code**:

```
import string
import pandas as pd

base = 'https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/?ajaxsrch='

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

letters.extend(range(0, 10))
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in letters:
    URL = base + str(i)
    df1=pd.read_html(URL)[0]
    df = df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

print(df[['Name','Codename','Socket','Released']]) #This will give you 1739 records

#If you want to delete duplicates use this
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='first', inplace=True)
print(df[['Name','Codename','Socket','Released']]) #This will give you 595 records
#Import into Csv file
df[['Name','Codename','Socket','Released']].to_csv("cpu_csv.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: have you noticed that he's removing the duplicates based on the column `Name`?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη : I have verified that the text of all the columns are duplicated here not only the first column so `None` will work here.

Comment: am getting `595` based on removing duplicate for column `Name`

Comment: you welcome :P next hint, we can call `all in` using [ajax for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436347/use-a-for-loop-within-an-ajax-call/11436706) with one `get` request but that's will count as a `hack` which i don't advise with.

Comment: If you look at the website link and go to the manufacter filter option it would indicate there are 2210 unique entries this is what's throwing me off.

Comment: This makes me think there is a limit on returned results and due to common naming schemes some are never showing up...

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import string


items = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase


def main(url):
    data = []
    for item in items:
        print(f"{item}")
        df = pd.read_html(url.format(item))[0]
        df = df[["Name", "Codename", "Socket", "Released"]]
        data.append(df)
    data = pd.concat(data)
    data.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep="first",inplace=True)
    data.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/?ajaxsrch={}")
```

Total Output is `596` based on removing duplicates By column `Name`.

[View Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/7ad5ba47a1401eb208a7688d5eba6ea1/data.csv)

Sample of output:

[image]

Comment: If you look at the website link and go to the manufacter filter option it would indicate there are 2210 unique entries this is what's throwing me off.

Comment: @Uskompuf mind to share that part? take screen-snip as i couldn't figure that point

Comment: I'm on mobile but following this link: https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/ up the top I can see filter options. Here is a screenshot from my phone: https://imgur.com/a/R9R5nIB

Comment: So do we just add &_=unixtimestamp to the end of the url?

Comment: @Uskompuf you will can't get all, just verified it now. the limit per result is `50` for each query. so `A-Z` plus `0-9` = `36` items. each single item will return `50` result without the header column, so `50 x 36 = 1800`

Comment: So there is no other way to query them all the problem is lots with similar names.

Comment: you do have 1739 because `j` returning `2` items and `w` returning `37` items. which means 50x34 + 39 = 1739

Comment: @Uskompuf let me check something, it's all depending server side. as they limiting `ajax live search`

Comment: Ok thanks I'm not very proficient in Ajax so it's a big help, I meant lots of a-z return duplicates where I need all 2210 unique entries

Comment: @Uskompuf well, actually it's will not be possible. they limited the input query to be reflected on `Name` column, so all your query will one interact with Name column. open that [link](https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/?ajaxsrch=2020) and you will understand

Comment: Ok, looks like I'll have to query it everytime with a name to get the data I require, you don't know of anyway to try different input combinations untill all possible results have been found?

Comment: @Uskompuf you can contact the site and asking for `static` keyword to call `all in`, since they do have an `API`, i believe they will not refuse. whatever you will do, you are restricted for result given